# Unable to move a div top value with percentage

Tags: html, css, position, percentage

I am working on a webpage with a two column set up. I have everything divided into two columns and have a container for each. I am attempting to move a div that contains an h1 heading. It is in position: relative and I am trying to move it based on percentage so it still looks good when a browser resizes. I can move the left/right fine with percentage, but I am unable to move the top or bottom. It works with px but then is messed up when the browser resizes. What am I doing wrong, what do I need to do to be able to move it with top in percentage?

here is the html (It's not actually in one line, but for some reason it doesn't want to go onto here in the way it actually is):

```
<div class = "aboutuscontainer2">        <a href="http://s1379.photobucket.com/user/Staroson/media/image1_zpsd2ppwgmq.jpg.html" target="_blank"><img id = "pic" src="http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah138/Staroson/image1_zpsd2ppwgmq.jpg" border="0" alt=" photo image1_zpsd2ppwgmq.jpg"/></a><div class = "developerhead"><h1> Meet the developer:</h1></div></div></div>
```

here is the css:

```css
.aboutuscontainer2 {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    top: 60px;
    right: 0%;
    border: solid white 1px;
    width: 47.3%;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#pic {
    position: relative;
    left: 67%;
    top: 2px;
    width: 32%;
}

.developerhead {
    position: relative;
    color: yellow;
    top: 0%;
    left: 10%;
}
```

Comment: Wanna show some HTML please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 0):

It's because the container/column does not have a set height. Top percentages are based on the the container, and the container does not have a set height.

Comment: Html is now added.. my fault